# Query integrating Fortran and C++ code

Tags: c++, integration, fortran

I'm trying to integrate some C++ code into Fortran.
I have a doubt with equivalences between types,

is Fortran **integer*1** equivalent to C++ **bool**?¿ if not, what is the correct C++ equivalent type?¿

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quoting from [this link](http://fortran.comsci.us/etymology/type/char.html):

> The INTEGER(1) type should be used for large arrays when memory is at
>   a premium for variables which will have only positive, negative, and
>   zero whole number values within the range of -129 to 127..

So, I'd say its `C/C++` equivalent would be a `signed char`. The equivalent of `bool` is Fortran's `logical` type.

EDIT: M.S.B.'s answer is way better than mine; you're way better off doing what (s)he suggested.

Comment: I would say the equivalent is `int8_t` since there might exist systems with multibyte `char`-s.

Comment: Fortran logical is frequently 4 bytes but can be one -- risky to match to a type from another language.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to use the Fortran ISO_C_Binding which provides types that match C types.  That approach is compiler and platform independent.  I'm less sure about C++ types but if you are sure of their C equivalent you should be good.   The ISO_C_Binding provides the Fortran type C_BOOL to match the C type _Bool.   The binding provides a long list of equivalent types.  One place that the list appears is in the chapter "Intrinsic Modules" of the gfortran manual.  Also see the "Mixed Language Programming" chapter.  While I have cited the gfortran manual, as part of the Fortran 2003 language standard these features aren't particular to that compiler.

P.S.  A comment suggests the use of int8_t.   The matching type, on the Fortran side with the ISO C Binding, is C_INT8_T.